# Magento 2. What is the recommend way to disable a core cron job?

Tags: magento2, cron

- Magento comes with it's own cron jobs.
- What is the recommended/cleanest way to disable on of such crons?
- I could do a rewrite of the worker class but I'm guessing there is an easier way.

Any pointers are much appreciated. Thanks.